# Trello-like Kanban Board for React Native

Tags: react, kanban, trello

As stated in the title, I want to use a kanban board in my react native application, but couldn't find any components.
I found some packages like https://github.com/rcdexta/react-trello and others but they're for ReactJS.
Is there a ready-to-use component for react native or am I better off starting from scratch myself?